# Combining values of 2 columns n excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns in excel:

name

AAA

BBB

CCC

and 
Number

1

2

3

I need in the next column to have combination of all the values in both columns:

CombColumn

AAA1

AAA2

AAA3

BBB1

BBB2

BBB3

CCC1

CCC2

CCC3

How do I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VBA is ok then you can accomplish it with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Combine()
Dim rowA As Long, rowB As Long, rowC As Long

Range("C:C").ClearContents

rowC = 2

rowA = 2
Do While Range("A" & rowA).Value <> ""
    rowB = 2
    Do While Range("B" & rowB).Value <> ""
        Range("C" & rowC).Value = Range("A" & rowA).Value & Range("B" & rowB).Value
        rowB = rowB + 1
        rowC = rowC + 1
    Loop
    rowA = rowA + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Note that code has no error checking where your actual number of values may produce more than maximum rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `=CONCATENATE(A2,"",B2)` in new column and for more knowledge have a look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-the-contents-of-multiple-cells-3a86c317-6b91-4f1d-8781-203320aefdce